# ListBox ScrollIntoView from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am animating the SelectedIndex of a ListBox using a StoryBoard.

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="FlipBook" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Selector.SelectedIndex)" Storyboard.TargetName="FlipBookView">
            <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
            <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
        </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

When the SelectedIndex changes, I would like the ListBox to automatically (and instantly) scroll to that item.

I believe ListBox.[ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will do exactly what I want, but I need it to be triggered automatically when the SelectedIndex changes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is create `Behaviors` using `System.Windows.Interactivity`. You would have to reference it manually in your project.

Given a control which doesn't expose `SelectedItems` e.g., (ListBox, DataGrid)

You can create a behavior class something like this

```
public class ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Assuming your selection mode is single.
        AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(e.AddedItems[0]);
    }
```

And on your `XAML` I would do the `Binding` like this where `i` is `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` and `behaviors` is the namespace of your `Behavior` class

```
<ListBox>
 <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior/>
 </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

Assuming that your `DataContext` for the `ListBox` has the `SelectedItems` property in the `ViewModel` then it will automatically update the `SelectedItems`. You have encapsulated the `event` subscribing from the `View` i.e.,

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

You can change the `Behavior` class to be of type `DataGrid` if you want.

Comment: Would this offer anything that scrolling into view on the SelectionChanged event wouldn't? I have done the following, but hoped to do it without code-behind if possible:

  `private void SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
   ListBox FlipBook = ((sender as ListBox) as ListBox);
    FlipBook.ScrollIntoView(FlipBook.SelectedItem);
  }`

Comment: It is not code behind in your `View`. It is an object declared in your `View` that is encapsulated with the event handlers. In my experience, behaviors is the cleanest way to attach events to `ViewModel` without using third party frameworks like `Caliburn.Micro`